# Facebook Profile Subscriber Count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, subscription, subscriber

Is there a method in the API to query the number of subscribers for one of the new profiles? I am talking about the new profiles (not pages), like this one for Tyra Banks:

http://www.facebook.com/XOXOTYTY

I can see on that page that she has 696k subscribers (more specifically, 696,833 as it shows when you search for her profile), but I cannot find that number in the graph.

I know that /userId/subscribers gives a list of my subscribers (which is awesome), but many pages that I'm querying have over 10k subscribers, so it doesn't list them all, and I just need the count.

Comment: Are you want to count the users who like your post etc?right?

Answer (score 1):

Only [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) object have [`subscribers`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscribers/) connection.
For [`page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) you can get count of "fans" by looking for `likes` property.

**Update:**
If you're looking for subscribers count on `user` object you need to use paging to get all the list, since there is no way to get only count of this data (currently, I hope this will be added later, since it's a really in high-demand by some players)...

Yet now you're out of luck since there is a [BUG #134805496634011](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134805496634011) with paging, so you may only get first page. There is `limit` argument but it's can't be whooping 697k for sure...

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.  :)

Comment: I rephrased my question, I am not looking for page fans. I am indeed looking for user subscribers.