# Get facebook profile subscribers count with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, function, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Profile Subscriber Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945917/facebook-profile-subscriber-count)

Is there any way to get number of facebook profile subscribers, but without any access token or something like that? For example, at my facebook profile I have 500 subscrbiers. I want to return this number with PHP, but without any access token or something like that. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: norfavrell, nothing useful, I need an concret answer. Yes or not! If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a user's subscriber count without a valid access token that has at least the `user_subscriptions` or `friends_subscriptions` permission.

Once you have that, you can get a user's subscriber count with this code:

```
<?php
$fburl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID/subscribers/'
$fbac = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents($fburl.'&access_token='.$fbac ) );
printf('You have %d subscribers', $result->summary->total_count );
```